# React Native - Detect when view goes offscreen Flatlist

Tags: facebook, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `Flatlist` element that renders a collection of Views that could be Images or Videos, similar to a Facebook feed. Is there any way to detect when a View will disappear from screen so I could stop automatic playback of video elements?

Currently my `Flatlist` component has a `scrollHandler` attached that detects the offset of the content and calculates the view number.

```
scrollHandler(event){

    let postHeight = 200;
    var currentOffset = Number(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);

    this.offsetActual=currentOffset;
    this.velOffset=currentOffset-this.prevOffset;
    this.prevOffset=currentOffset;

    let postNumber=(currentOffset/postHeight);
    // Any additional logic
}
```

Could there be something like `UITableViewCell` will disappear but for the `Flatlist` elements? Or any other handler where I could attach "will disappear" logic?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of [onViewableItemsChanged](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#onviewableitemschanged) prop. This way you'll know which items are visible at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.